# Swift iOS -How to dismiss an activity indicator with timer if a network call to Firebase takes to long

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

When I send data to `Firebase` I sometimes have to use `nested completion blocks` to send `data` to different `nodes`.

*the actual code is below but here's an example*

```
buttonPressed{
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    levelTwoRef //send levelTwo data run 1st callback
         scoreRef  //send score data run 2nd callback
            powerRef //send power data run 3rd  callback
               lifeRef //send life data run Last callback for dispatch_async...
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                     activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                     performSegueWithIdentifier....
                  }
```

I present an `activityIndicator` once the button is pressed. Most of the time everything goes ok but I've seen the call fail around the `scoreRef` and `PowerRef` which would be the 1st and 2nd `callback`. The thing is I don't remove the `activityIndicator` until the last `completion block` runs so the `activityIndicator` spins indefinitely (it never makes it to there). I also block the user interface for that view while the spinner is spinning so there isn't much the user can do.

A few people suggested I put a `timer` on the call and if it doesn't get completed in X time frame I present a cancel button to stop the operation. **I have no idea how to add a timer**. For the cancel button I'd just use an `alertController` to stop everything

I have 2 questions:

1. **How do I add a `timer` to the calls and at which point do I use it?** I say that because sometimes it completes other times it
   fails at different blocks.
2. **How do I determine the amount of time everything is supposed to get completed in?** I say because it usually takes a couple of secs
   to successfully complete but other times it's taken up to 45 secs.
   If the network is congested the calls might not fail, they're just
   waiting.

*I'm still using Swift 2.2 because books that I reference are written in it.*

Code:

```
class LevelOneCompletedController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var completedLevelButton: UIButton!

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

var levelDict = [String:AnyObject]()
var scoreDict = [String:AnyObject]()
var powerDict = [String:AnyObject]()
var lifeDict = [String:AnyObject]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(self.uid!)
}


@IBAction func completedLevelButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
     self.completedLevelButton.enabled = false
     self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
     self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
     self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
     self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
     self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
     self.boardPassed()
}


fun boardPassed(){

   let levelTwoRef = self.ref.child("levelTwo").childByAutoID()
   levelTwoRef?.updateChildValues(self.levelDict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in 
            if error != nil{....}

     let scoreRef = self.ref.child("Score").childByAutoID()
     scoreRef?updateChildValues(self.scoreDict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in 
            if error != nil{....}

       let powerRef = self.ref.child("Power").childByAutoID()
       powerRef?updateChildValues(self.powerDict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in 
            if error != nil{....}

         let lifeRef = self.ref.child("Life").childByAutoID()
         lifeRef?updateChildValues(self.lifeDict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in 
            if error != nil{....}

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
               self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("levelTwoSeque", sender: self)
               self.completedLevelButton.enabled = true
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without timer would be to keep track of the connection state. You can listen to the state in the following way:

```
let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false {
    print("Connected")
  } else {
    print("Not connected")
  }
})
```

You could keep the updated state in a variable and check it before every request then start/stop the `activityIndicator` as you wish.

More information can be found here: [Detecting Connection State](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities).

Comment: hey man thanks for helping. I actually figured this out weeks ago but didn't get a chance to update my answer (I have quite a few to update). I used a combination of GCD's DispatchWorkItem, async_after{ .now() + someTime},and with Firebase you can use multi location updates when updating child values. I'm going to put all the code up next week. I'm focusing on finishing my app. Thanks though!

Comment: I have upvoted your question, I have also faced this issue today. How much is the someTime value exactly? My opinion is that the solution with observer seems to be more precise/correct. :) Thanks